# Why column_a += @value is not equal to column_a = column_a + @value in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a stored procedure to update data in a table. It looks like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.sample
SET column_a += @value
WHERE id = @id
```

What I found is it update without sum first. The result is like below command:

```
UPDATE dbo.sample
SET column_a = @value
WHERE id = @id
```

I have to use `SET column_a = column_a + @value` to make it update properly. I want to know why SQL Server does not sum the expression on the right before assign to the left. I tested with variables and it works. It does not work only in this case.

The command that I use right now is:

```
UPDATE dbo.sample
SET column_a = column_a + @value
WHERE id = @id
```

Comment: You're wrong. Please test again. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78376/1)

Comment: I just tested it again on my machine. I am not sure why. It may related to transaction that I use inside the code.

Comment: Can you supply a complete runnable test case that reproduces this issue on your machine?

Comment: Are you **REALLY** connecting to a **2008** version of SQL Server? Can you run `SELECT @@Version` on your SQL Server and see what it reports back?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following script. It is working fine for me.

I suggest you to try this once. let me know if the problem still persists.

```
create table #temp1(id int, prodName varchar(max))

insert into #temp1 values(1,'a')
insert into #temp1 values(2,'b')
insert into #temp1 values(3,'c')
insert into #temp1 values(4,'d')

select * from #temp1

declare @var varchar(1);
set @var = '5'; --note that i even tried declaring it as a varchar. it still works!
update #temp1
set id +=@var

select * from #temp1

drop table #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

> **column_a += @value** is  equal to **column_a = column_a + @value** in SQL Server 2008

its just the first one is short